# Without having the ability to change them, how can you avoid this XAML-caused namespace collision?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, namespaces

Unfortunately, due to issues that are frustratingly out of my control, I'm forced to use components with namespaces which I cannot change.  Because of the way they have structured them, it's causing collisions in the generated code-behind.

Again, unfortunately, I do not have access to the code which defines these namespaces so they cannot be changed. Also, I've also tried demonstrating the issue to the owners explaining why this is a very bad design, but I've been told for other reasons, changing them is not an option, so I'm forced to find a work-around.

Here's a simplified example to illustrate the issue. Consider a solution with two projects, a 'Core' library, and the consuming application:

**Items in 'Core' Library**

- `ModelA` (Namespace: `SomeFeature.Core.Models`)
- `ModelB` (Namespace: `SomeFeature.Core.Models`)

**Items in 'ConsumingApp' (References 'Core') **

- `MainWindow` (Namespace: `ConsumingApp.SomeFeature`)
- `TestControl` (Namespace: `SomeFeature.Controls`)

The cause of the collision can be explained in three steps:

1. `SomeFeature` is both the root of one namespace, and a child of another
2. `TestControl` is defined as being in the rooted version of the namespace (same as the library), not the one `MainWindow` is in.
3. Code-generation ends up placing the generated variables for those XAML elements in the namespace scope of `MainWindow`, not that matching what's actually in the XAML.

Now if these were manually-defined variables in non-generated code-behind, dealing with this is easy. By simply adding the prefix `global::` it 'roots' the namespace you're typing, thus removing all ambiguity.

```
namespace ConsumingApp.SomeFeature{

    public partial class MainWindow{

        // Note the 'global::' prefix
        global::SomeFeature.Controls.TestControl MainTestControl { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The above will ensure that it always resolves relative to the global `SomeFeature` namespace and never the nested `ConsumerApp.SomeFeature` namespace.  Pretty straight forward.

However, the auto-generated code-behind from the XAML parser doesn't include that `global::` prefix, so in the generated code, you actually get this:

```
namespace ConsumingApp.SomeFeature{

    public partial class MainWindow{

        // Note: without the 'global::' prefix, this resolves to
        // 'ConsumingApp.SomeFeature.Controls.TestControl'
        // which doesn't actually exist, causing the mentioned issue.
        SomeFeature.Controls.TestControl MainTestControl { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Which results in this error:

> Error  CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Controls' does not exist in the namespace 'ConsumingApp.SomeFeature' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

As noted in the code comments, this is because it's not looking for this class path...

```
SomeFeature.Controls.TestControl
```

but rather this one:

```
ConsumingApp.SomeFeature.Controls.TestControl
```

which doesn't exist, ergo the error.

The fix would be to somehow get the auto-generated code to explicitly output the `global::` but I don't know how to do that, or even if it can be done.

Things I've tried:

1. Arguing for them to change their namespaces! (I lost!)
2. Explicitly referencing the assembly in the XAML import:
3. Defining aliases in the non-generated code-behind
4. Searching for aliases in the XAML world (not found)
5. Avoiding naming the element, and instead manually searching for the control via other properties. *(Horrible, but this does work!)*

So is there anything that can be done here to get the code-generator to include the 'global::' prefix, or is there another way to do this?

Comment: This may be some use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/how-to-use-the-global-namespace-alias

Comment: Yeah, I referenced that in my question as being available in the code, but not in the XAML-generated code. That's the entire point of the question.

Comment: Would referencing the assembly change anything? xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:SomeFeature.Controls; Assembly:TestControl"

Comment: No, tried that.  It still just outputs the portion without the global.  At least I believe I have a compelling case to get the namespaces changed.  This is pretty bad!

Comment: Appears my comment above is incorrect, it should be "Assembly=TestControl"

Comment: Another down-vote?!  Really?!?!  I'd love to know why!  We have a problem that we're dealing with and I've explained exactly what's going on, and I'm seeking potential solutions.  Why is this getting down-voted?  What's the reason? It's a completely valid, and well-explained question about a problem we're forced to face thanks to this ridiculous namespace issue.  So how does this question fall short?  It's really frustrating when people do that as it has the exact opposite response they think, making a valid question that may help someone seem less important. Not good SO etiquette at all.